# Can I install 12.04 and then upgrade to 13.04 to get latest features?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I have a netbook 1015CX by Asus. When I install 13.04, it lags drastically and not usable at all. Hence yesterday I installed 12.04 and it seems to be working great. But as my netbook has only 10 inches. of screen I am not able to re-size the icon size etc. of the launch bar. I saw that option to change icon size in 13.04.

Hence my question, can I upgrade 12.04 to 13.04 without the lagness and get all the latest features ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you upgrade you will get the same experience as if you loaded it directly.

In fact, I just attempted to to a upgrade to 13.04 from LTS on my netbook (Asus A0751h) and it warned me that it would be slow, so I stayed on LTS.